# Try catch stuck in an infinite loop while downloading data in R

Tags: r, quandl

I'm downloading stock data from quandl and have used a trycatch to catch stocks whose data cannot be downloaded. out of some 800 stocks, 9 are giving an error but the try catch is stuck in an infinite loop and does not write the csv files for the other stocks. I don't want the command to try downloading the data again. How do i get out of the loop?

Here is the code:

## constant declaration

```
date_Start<-Sys.Date()-1
date_End<-Sys.Date()


#loop for downloading todays's data
stocksData<-lapply(stockName,function(x,start_date,end_date){
  startDate<-date_Start
  endDate<-date_End

  path<- path_Data

  from.dat <- as.Date(startDate, format="%m/%d/%y")
  to.dat <- as.Date(endDate, format="%m/%d/%y")

  stockNameNew <- gsub("[/]","_",x)
  #to remove the "." from stocknames and replace it by "_"

  for(i in stockName){

  downloadData <-tryCatch(Quandl(i,type = "xts",start_date =    from.dat,end_date = to.dat),error=identity) 
    if(inherits(downloadData, "error"))
    cat("Symbol '", i, "' not downloadable!\n", sep = "")


  }


  #downloads data from quandl

  stockData <- as.data.frame(downloadData) 



  write.csv(stockData,fileName)
  #csv file is created
})
```

The output is:

> Symbol 'NSE/GSPL' not downloadable!
>   Symbol 'NSE/INDHOTEL' not downloadable!
>   Symbol 'NSE/KOTAKGOLD' not downloadable!
>   Symbol 'NSE/GSPL' not downloadable!
>   Symbol 'NSE/INDHOTEL' not downloadable!
>   Symbol 'NSE/KOTAKGOLD' not downloadable!

```
repeated continuously...
```

Comment: Who says this is an infinite loop?  It seems to me that it will only iterate over the length of `stockName`.  My guess is that one of the web service calls to get stock info is hanging for some reason.

Comment: OK here is an idea: Can you figure out on which symbol it crashes, and then try making a _single_ call for that stock information?  This would give you a handle on the root cause.  You could then try investigating this stock and see if maybe the web service has some problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you `lapply` over `stockName` and also do a `for` loop over `stockName`. Isn't that why it's repeating? So if you get those three errors, you will get them as many times as the length of `stockName`. Also, you're not using `stockNameNew` or `x` in the loop.